# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create an agent for trading using LSTMS, however I am having some conflicts.

```
def batch_train(self, batch_size):
   batch = []
   for i in range(len(self.memory) - batch_size + 1, len(self.memory)):
      batch.append(self.memory[i])

for state, action, reward, next_state, done in batch:
  if not done:
    reward = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])
    
  target = self.model.predict(state)
  target[0][action] = reward
  
  self.model.fit(state, target, epochs=1, verbose=0)
  
if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_final:
  self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

## HERE CALL FUNCTION

```
if len(trader.memory) > batch_size:
  print(type(batch_size))
  trader.batch_train(batch_size) # error happens here
```

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported
> object type numpy.ndarray).

Comment: To make the problem reproducible you should declare for us trade.memory and batch_size

Answer (score 0):

Is your array boolean? Try converting it to float32 if it is not yet.

```
X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)
```